# Why am I getting CNFE for FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer and CannotGetJdbcConnectionException after removing JPA from spring-boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot project and I wanted to remove JPA. However, after doing this I see the following while starting

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:304) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:224) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:69) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:64) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:58) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:491) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExceptionReporters(SpringApplication.java:835) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at com.cbusha.be.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:24) ~[main/:na]

2024-03-24T11:52:15.124-04:00 TRACE 9108 --- [cbusha-be] [           main] o.s.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers    : Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3549) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:2227) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.findConstructor(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:405) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.forClass(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:394) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:227) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.loadFailureAnalyzers(FailureAnalyzers.java:69) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:64) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzers.<init>(FailureAnalyzers.java:58) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader$FactoryInstantiator.instantiate(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:382) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:228) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:206) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.load(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:160) ~[spring-core-6.1.2.jar:6.1.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:491) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExceptionReporters(SpringApplication.java:835) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-3.2.1.jar:3.2.1]
        at com.cbusha.be.BackendApplication.main(BackendApplication.java:24) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
```

My gradle deps look like this

```
dependencies {

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.+')
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:s3'
    implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:rds'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.39'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}
```

I tried adding

```
//    TODO Why do I need these
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
```

and the following in my application.yml

```
spring:
  flyaway:
    enabled: false
```

But I still get the same error. What am I missing how do I remove JPA and avoid these issues? I have confirmed no classes are still using JPA annotations.

I also tried removing the `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure'` dependency and rerunning and oddly I get the same issue

Also I am using Java 21 (OpenJDK)

Another thing possibly of note is I use `apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'`

I have removed all deps except

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.12.39'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

and I still get the issue, I also tried adding

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'`

But again same issue

Answer (score 0):

So this appears to be a red herring, I do get

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationScriptMissingFailureAnalyzer`

and I do get

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException`

and even

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: liquibase/exception/ChangeLogParseException`

But only when it cannot reach the cassandra server, I thought they were separate issues given the context but a little farther down I see...

`Caused by: io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null`

I do seem to have 1 more problem, however, and that is when using docker container names instead of localhost I seem to still get the issue. For more information see

[Why can't get a connection to Cassandra running on Docker from a Spring Boot instace using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra on first boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78215539/why-cant-get-a-connection-to-cassandra-running-on-docker-from-a-spring-boot-ins)